# Call a method from parent component via props, when clicking on a button

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, react-props

I'm stuck because of many multiple solutions to the problem I have, but no clear explanation for a beginner like me.

I'm building my first todo list app. 
I have an App file and a ToDo child component.

From the child Todo, I'm calling the deleteTodo method, included within my parent app component, using `props`, but the console doesn't display any result when I click on the button.

What am I missing?

**ToDo.js** (full code)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ToDo extends Component { //define a class that extends Component
   render() {
   return (
       <li>
          <span>{ this.props.description }</span>
          <button onClick ={this.props.deleteTodo}>Delete</button>
       </li>
   );
 }
}
export default ToDo; //the component is made to export the data
```

**App.js** (for full code: https://jsfiddle.net/apjc6gk4/)

```
[...]

deleteTodo() {
    console.log("to do deleted");
  }
[...]
```

Comment: Make sure you are sending deleteTodo as prop to Todo component like <Todo deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo} />

Answer (score 0):

You need pass deleteTodo to ToDo comoponent

```
<ToDo key={ index }          
      deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo.bind(this)}
      description={ todo.description }
      isCompleted={ todo.isCompleted }
      toggleComplete={ () => this.toggleComplete(index)}
      isDeleted={todo.isDeleted}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `deleteTodo` method as prop to Todo component

```
<ToDo key={ index } description={ todo.description } isCompleted={ todo.isCompleted } toggleComplete={ () => this.toggleComplete(index)} isDeleted = {todo.isDeleted}/>
```

Pass this method as prop to Todo component, and then call it

```
<ToDo key={ index } description={ todo.description } isCompleted={ todo.isCompleted } toggleComplete={ () => this.toggleComplete(index)} isDeleted = {todo.isDeleted} deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo.bind(this)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, following steps help me same as your case.
I hope to help you with my steps.

1. Define function in parent component to receive props from child component.
2. In parent component, pass function name to child component by props.
3. In child component, call props function when button clicked.
4. You can see result in the parent component from child.